# How to specify the named parameter in externalized jpa native query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I need to pass the dynamic parameter *:id* to the native query which I'd externalized in XML,
However I have already getting the parameter in my repository method by using `@param`,but that is not working.Shall I required some more work around in order to pass this parameter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd"
                 version="1.0">
    <named-native-query name="RoleModulePermissionMapping.getAllNavigationMeunPermissionsByUserId">
        <query>
            <![CDATA[select
            md.name module_name,
            mdg.name module_group_name,
            pr.description,
            ur.name
            from {h-schema}nl_system_user s
            inner join {h-schema}nl_user_role_mapping urm on s.id=urm.sys_user_id
            inner join {h-schema}nl_user_role ur on ur.id=urm.role_id
            inner join {h-schema}nl_role_module_permission_mapping rmpm on rmpm.user_role_id=ur.id
            inner join {h-schema}nl_module md on md.id=rmpm.module_id
            inner join {h-schema}nl_module_group mdg on mdg.id=md.module_grp_id
            inner join {h-schema}nl_permission pr on pr.id=rmpm.permission_id
            where s.id=:id and pr.description !='restricted']]>
        </query>
    </named-native-query>
</entity-mappings>
```

In **JPARepository**

```
     @Repository
public interface RoleModulePermissionMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleModulePermissionMapping, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<RoleModulePermissionMapping> {
    public List<IUserRoleDTO> getAllNavigationMeunPermissionsByUserId(@Param("id") long id); 
}

public interface IUserRoleDTO {

    public String getRole();
    public String getModuleGroupName();
    public String getModuleName();
    public String getRouteUrl();
    public String getPermissions();
    public String getLevelOfAccess();
    public String getMdgDisplayOrder();
    public String getMdDisplayOrder();
    public String getMdgIcon();
    public String MdIcon();
    public Boolean isNavigableMenu();
}
```

As per the logs, query is working fine and but parameter's value is not appended at run time, please let me know the workaround for the same

Comment: I am not sure, everything seems to be fine, what I suspicious about is, the alias you used in the query, are you using the interface to bind the column data?

Comment: Yeah I have created an Interface, and define all the getters for the same, Please see my edits